# Get all XML Nodes with Child elements and their values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using this XML structre

```
<root>  
  <StandardValues>    
      <ButtonYES>Ja</ButtonYES>
      <ButtonNO>Nei</ButtonNO>
  <tooltips>
    <tooltipOK>OK</tooltipOK>
    <tooltipCancel>Cancel</tooltipCancel>
  </tooltips>
  </StandardValues>
  <Page1>
    <Key_Head alias="custom value">2011 Applications</Key_Head>
    <Key_Title alias="custom values scsc">Title from 2011</Key_Title>
    <Key_Param1>Parameter value</Key_Param1>
  </Page1>
  <Page2>
      <Page_Head>2011 Applications</Page_Head>
      <page_Title>Title from 2011</page_Title>
      <CustomParam1>Parameter value</CustomParam1>
  </Page2>
</root>
```

How can i find child nodes values alone as a List .

For example here in this XML Page1 have 3 child nodes i just want those 3 names and its values No need to include Nodes like  "root" "StandardValues" "tooltips"  "Page2" "Page1" etc in the result list . I just want the XML Elements in the very base level with some values only

I tried this but no success

```
var elements_list = doc.Root
                        .Elements().Where(p=>p.HasElements==false)
                        .Select(d => new
                        {
                            NodeName = (string)d.Name.LocalName,
                            Value = d.Value, // equal to id you are searching for
                            AttributeValue = (d.Attribute("alias") != null) ? 
                                                d.Attribute("alias").Value : ""  
                        }).ToList();

foreach (var s in elements_list)
{
    string ss = string.Format("{0} -  {1} && {2}", s.NodeName, s.Value, s.AttributeValue);
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `(d.Attribute("alias") != null) ? d.Attribute("alias").Value : ""` can be written as `(string)d.Attribute("alias") ?? ""`.

Comment: Want to include page 2 children too .. Only cHildrens of every nodes

Comment: @CharlesMager I am keeping node name as attribute value if its null Thats why i kept code like that

Comment: @JibinMathew The code I suggested returns exactly the same result?

Answer (score 4):

`Elements` method returns element's direct children only and not sub-children.

Use `Descendants` instead:

```
 doc.Root.Descendants().Where(p=>!p.HasElements).Select(....
```

Comment: perfect did the trick . But i have a node with a bold value in it without CData like   <CustomParam1>Paramete<b>bold param</b>r value</CustomParam1>  And this code returns that <b> tag as well. Any wayt o avoid this? Currently i am getting <Customparam1> and <b> as 2 nodes

Comment: @JibinMathew I've tested string you've provided in comment. Are you sure you're getting `CustomParam` as well as `b` node? At my side - I'm getting only `b` - and this is totally according to the initial goal "get only "leaf" nodes without children"

Comment: Sorry for lack of observation. Its the same here only <b> no CustomParam.
Also when i add CData everything is fine . I think using cData is the xml way , but i dont have much control over xml file